# How to use Contravariance in Java with Classes

Tags: java, generics, variance, contravariance

I am learning Java variance.

I am getting the Covariant to work but not Contravariance where I can accept a super type.

I have a simple class hierarchy for this:

Animal,
Cat,
Lion

Then I have two classes as Generic holders:

CovariantAnimalHolder
ContraVariantHolder

The Covariant works fine but Contravariance isnt working.

Here is the code:

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Animal() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class Cat extends Animal {
    private boolean isWild;

    public Cat(boolean isWild) {
        this.isWild = isWild;
    }

    public Cat(){

    }

    public boolean isWild() {
        return isWild;
    }

    public void setWild(boolean wild) {
        isWild = wild;
    }
}

public class Lion extends Cat{

    private boolean isExtinct;

    public Lion (boolean isExtinct) {
        this.isExtinct = isExtinct;
    }

    public Lion () {

    }

    public boolean isExtinct() {
        return isExtinct;
    }

    public void setExtinct(boolean extinct) {
        isExtinct = extinct;
    }
}
```

Animal Holders:

```
public class CovariantAnimalHolder<T extends Cat> {
    private T animalHolder;

    public T getAnimalHolder() {
        return animalHolder;
    }

    public void setAnimalHolder(T animalHolder) {
        this.animalHolder = animalHolder;
    }
}
```

Main program:

So far great

```
public class VarianceMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //This works
        CovariantAnimalHolder<Lion> lionCovariantAnimalHolder = new CovariantAnimalHolder<Lion>();

        //This works:
        CovariantAnimalHolder<Cat> catCovariantAnimalHolder = new CovariantAnimalHolder<>();

        //This should not work, Perfect!
        //CovariantAnimalHolder<Animal> animalCovariantAnimalHolder = new CovariantAnimalHolder<Animal>();
    }
}
```

But when I create the ContraVariant holder I am getting some basic errors which I can't understand:

```
public class ContravariantAnimalHolder<T super Cat>{
    private T animalHolder;
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: That’s not really what you would use contrivance for.  With conscience, you know T is (a type of) Cat, so you know that you can call Cat methods on that instance.  With `<T super Animal>`, that doesn’t give anything like that - you could validly have `ContravariantAnimalHolder<Object>`.  So contrarian is mostly used will Collections etc rather than operating on single instances - eg if you have a `List<T super Cat >` and you have an instance of a T, then you know you can add that instance to that List (which might be you have a List<Animal> you can add your Lion to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you cannot define a generic type as a covariant or contravariant, as you can in other languages, for example, in scala

Instead, in java, what you define are generic types with [*Upper bounds*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) which limit you to the use of `extends` when it comes to types, and you cannot use `super` with generic types, reason you cannot use it in your `ContravariantAnimalHolder` class.

You can, however define methods with [lower bounded wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html), which, depending on what you need may fit your needs for contravariant

Comment: I think, I need to get a more solid understanding about this, I have done this in Kotlin but still don't deeply understand the concept. I tried <? super T> and it still shows the same error,

Comment: Java and Kotlin work differently in this area.  In some places, including the generic parameters of classes, you can use extends and cannot use super in Java.

Comment: @theMyth I don't know if you're trying to use <? super T> in a class or in a method, you cannot use super *at all* in a class, only in methods, perhaps thats what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this @GAL, That helps, I think If I be completely honest, Im spending all day trying to understand why we have these two options, I think I can understand upper bound and the need for it, but I don't understand the need for <? super T> , maybe understanding a use case would help me, all the examples I find, don't give me a foundational understanding & Im very confused

Comment: If you could give me a small use case when we need lower bound wildcards and if there is a difference between ? and T, then that would help me to no end. When I read the example of that link in the Lower bounds, I don't understand why lower bound exists

Comment: What if I want to create a Consumer Interface ? I am not able to do this either ? Like in Kotlin where I can do in T ?